# Proof that the $\mathbb R P^n$ is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

In Tu's book on manifolds he proves on page 79 that the real projective space $\mathbb R P^n$ is Hausdorff by letting $S = \mathbb R^{n+1} - \{0\}$ and showing that
$$
R = \{(x,y) \in S\times S \mid y = tx \text{ for some } t\in \mathbb R^\times\}
$$
is a closed subset of $S\times S$. He explains that $R$ may be considered as the set of all $(n+1)\times 2$ matrices $[x\,y]$ in $S\times S$ of rank $\leq 1$, which is equivalent to requiring that all $2\times 2$ minors of the matrices $[x\, y]$ vanish. He then concludes that as the zero set of finitely many polynomials, $R$ is a closed subset of $S\times S$.

---

I'm still having trouble understanding why $R$ is a closed subset of $S\times S$. Why is this implied by the fact that all of the $2\times 2$ minors of elements of $R$ vanish? I know that the inverse image of a closed set, such as $\{0\}$, under a continuous map, is closed. But I'm not quite sure how to look at $R$ as the inverse image of $\{0\}$ under a continuous map. Should I be looking at it as a finite intersection of closed sets, one corresponding to each $2\times 2$ minor?

Comment: While not an answer to your specific question, another approach to showing $\mathbb RP^n$ is hausdorff is to view it as a quotient of $S^n$ under the antipodal action of $\mathbb Z/2$.  I suspect that the quotient of a Hausdorff space by any free and discrete action will be Hausdorff. Ignoring generalities, take two points in projective space, lift them to pairs of antipodal points of the sphere, and use the Hausdorf property to find open sets separating the 4 points.  Then, for each pair, take the intersection of the open sets and their antipodal images.  Project to projective space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument is that

1. Each $2\times 2$ minor is a polynomial, for example
   $$x_1y_2-x_2y_1,$$
   hence a continuous function $S\times S\to \mathbb R$.
2. The zero set of a continuous function is the preimage of the closed set $\{0\}$, hence closed.
3. Finite intersection ($R$) of closed sets is closed -- You are correct.